# Touchpad registers as pointer in X

Tags: xorg, touchpad, multi-touch, elantech

I got a new ASUS K501U laptop and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. I'm running kernel 4.7 although I had the same issue in 4.3. Multitouch features like two-finger scrolling aren't working. The touchpad is an Elantech touchpad, and Ubuntu doesn't appear to support it beyond generic drivers.

I've played around a lot with the X configuration. If I set the driver to `libinput` or `evdev`, it doesn't seem to work with multitouch and `synaptics` throws errors. The device is named `FTE1001:00 0B05:0101`, which is the I2C address of the device, and X detects it as a pointer instead of a touchpad, which appears to be the issue. It seems like Ubuntu doesn't recognize the device and by default assumes it's a pointer. Therefore, how can I tell Ubuntu to recognize it as a touchpad, not a pointer? Is the configuration for this in X or udev?

To be clear, this works (in an `x.conf.d` file entry):

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "psmouse pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection
```

and this doesn't:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "psmouse pointer catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection
```

Additionally, when I upgraded my kernel to 4.7, I noticed that DKMS was having issues building the `psmouse` driver:

```
/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/cypress_ps2.c: In function ‘cypress_process_packet’:
/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-x551c/build/src/cypress_ps2.c:543:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_assign_slots’
  input_mt_assign_slots(input, slots, pos, n);
```

I added a `0` as a fifth argument per the definition of `input_mt_assign_slots` from the Linux kernel multitouch library, and then DKMS seemed to build and install it correctly: `psmouse elantech-x551c`. However, if I set the driver to `psmouse` in the X config, X says it can't load the module (I don't even really understand what `psmouse` is for so that might be entirely naive). What relationship does the `psmouse` driver have to the drivers like `evdev` and `libinput`?

When I run `xinput --list-props` with my current setup, I get this:

```
Device 'FTE1001:00 0B05:0101':
    Device Enabled (137):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (139): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (263): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (264):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (265):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (266):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (259):    2821, 257
    Device Node (258):  "/dev/input/event14"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (267): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (269):  0
    Axis Labels (270):  "Rel X" (147), "Rel Y" (148), "Rel Vert Wheel" (262)
    Button Labels (271):    "Button Left" (140), "Button Unknown" (261), "Button Right" (142), "Button Wheel Up" (143), "Button Wheel Down" (144), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (145), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (146)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (272): 1, 1, 1
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (273):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (274):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (275): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (276): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (277):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (278):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (279):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (280):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (281):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (282):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (283): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (284):  0
```

Which again seems to imply that Ubuntu is recognizing it as mouse instead of as a touchpad.

**tl; dr** Ubuntu doesn't recognize my Elantech touchpad and assumes it's a pointer instead of a touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

I found something [here](//evilcodingmonkey.com/2014/01/23/ubuntu-activate-multi-touch-on-elantech):

> First, if you aren’t sure your computer was built with an Elantech touchpad, open a terminal, and type the following:
>
> ```
> cat /proc/bus/input/devices
> ```
>
> You should find a block containing a line looking like this one, which confirms you are on an Elantech touchpad:
>
> ```
> N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
> ```
>
> Download [this archive](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/+attachment/3941591/+files/psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz) (from Ubuntu’s bug reporting page).
>
> Open a terminal, and follow these steps (after [line] 4, you will have no mouse at all):
>
> ```
> cd ~/Downloads
> sudo dkms ldtarball psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz
> sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-x551c
> sudo rmmod psmouse
> sudo modprobe psmouse
> ```
>
> Enjoy multitouch!
>
> Source: [Elantech clickpad/touchpad lacks multitouch features](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/+index?comments=all)

I have verified the links, they are from launchpad. Also, the biiiig number of comments suggests the page is genuine, although there is no WOT rating yet; if someone wants to rate the page on WOT, please do. If it is a negative rating, also inform me in the comments, and I will delete this answer until I find another source.

Comment: the problem is that my touchpad isn't recognized by the system at all. windows reports it as elantech, as do my laptop's docs.

Comment: @singerng Have you tried these steps at all? You say that "the driver seems to be installed correctly", but many (official) repository drivers are **literally broken**. The links here are from Launchpad.

Comment: yeah, i have. this issue actually appears to be a bug in the linux kernel, so it's fine: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=120181

Comment: **WARNING:** WOT-ratings may be (partly) ok, but do **NOT install any WOT-software**, it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Oh gosh! I just uninstalled WOT as of Nov 7's announcement. I also deleted my mywot.com account.